# Slow boot in Ubuntu 18.10 (dual boot dell inspiron 5570)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 18.10

First of all I have tried many methods but they didn't worked.
I am using dell inspiron 5570 and dual booted ubuntu 18.10 (upgraded from 18.04) and windows.
Here are some outputs :

```
systemd-analyze 
Startup finished in 9.741s (firmware) + 8.671s (loader) + 5.543s (kernel) + 1min 1.259s (userspace) = 1min 25.215s
graphical.target reached after 1min 1.239s in userspace

    systemd-analyze critical-chain 
The time after the unit is active or started is printed after the "@" character.
The time the unit takes to start is printed after the "+" character.

graphical.target @1min 1.239s
└─multi-user.target @1min 1.239s
  └─teamviewerd.service @59.453s +1.785s
    └─network-online.target @59.451s
      └─NetworkManager-wait-online.service @45.485s +13.964s
        └─NetworkManager.service @38.320s +7.163s
          └─dbus.service @38.316s
            └─basic.target @37.136s
              └─sockets.target @37.136s
                └─snapd.socket @37.121s +14ms
                  └─sysinit.target @36.927s
                    └─haveged.service @36.926s
                      └─apparmor.service @32.777s +4.148s
                        └─local-fs.target @32.732s
                          └─boot-efi.mount @32.616s +116ms
                            └─systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-9EE8\x2d695F.serv
                              └─dev-disk-by\x2duuid-9EE8\x2d695F.device @30.536s

systemd-analyze blame
     24.686s dev-sda8.device
     20.600s systemd-journal-flush.service
     15.304s udisks2.service
     14.904s apport-autoreport.service
     14.380s networkd-dispatcher.service
     13.964s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
     13.053s ModemManager.service
     12.915s snapd.service
     12.856s accounts-daemon.service
     10.455s dev-loop9.device
     10.203s dev-loop18.device
     10.044s dev-loop19.device
      9.971s dev-loop20.device
      9.961s dev-loop13.device
      9.931s dev-loop11.device
      9.443s dev-loop17.device
      9.221s dev-loop10.device
      9.198s dev-loop12.device
      9.010s dev-loop15.device
      8.940s dev-loop16.device
      8.668s avahi-daemon.service
      8.594s dev-loop8.device
      8.491s networking.service
      8.425s dev-loop14.device
      8.236s systemd-logind.service
      8.236s thermald.service
      8.235s bluetooth.service
      8.232s grub-common.service
      8.226s gpu-manager.service
      8.192s alsa-restore.service
      8.189s apport.service
      8.072s dev-loop7.device
      7.677s dev-loop2.device
      7.414s dev-loop5.device
      7.163s NetworkManager.service
      7.162s wpa_supplicant.service
      7.101s rsyslog.service
      7.101s switcheroo-control.service
      6.810s plymouth-quit-wait.service
      6.290s dev-loop6.device
      6.178s colord.service
      6.115s dev-loop4.device
      5.934s dev-loop3.device
      5.876s dev-loop0.device
      5.867s dev-loop1.device
      4.568s systemd-udevd.service
      4.148s apparmor.service
      3.488s gdm.service
      2.794s systemd-rfkill.service
      2.264s keyboard-setup.service
      2.047s systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-9EE8\x2d695F.service
      2.001s systemd-resolved.service
      1.870s snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d26\x2d1604-74.mount
      1.854s openvpn.service
      1.788s snap-gnome\x2dcalculator-238.mount
      1.785s teamviewerd.service
      1.575s systemd-modules-load.service
      1.562s dns-clean.service
      1.509s systemd-sysusers.service
      1.484s fwupd.service
      1.468s polkit.service
      1.438s snap-gnome\x2dsystem\x2dmonitor-54.mount
      1.429s snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-808.mount
      1.428s systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
      1.428s snap-gnome\x2dsystem\x2dmonitor-51.mount
      1.388s snap-core-6034.mount
      1.377s snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-701.mount
      1.346s snap-gnome\x2dcalculator-222.mount
      1.318s grub-initrd-fallback.service
      1.317s snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-818.mount
      1.311s snap-core-6259.mount
      1.221s kerneloops.service
      1.196s pppd-dns.service
      1.195s sysstat.service
      1.036s systemd-sysctl.service
      1.013s snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d26\x2d1604-70.mount
       993ms console-setup.service
       992ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
       990ms packagekit.service
       886ms snap-core-6130.mount
       862ms swapfile.swap
       712ms snap-gnome\x2dcharacters-124.mount
       681ms systemd-backlight@backlight:intel_backlight.service
       679ms systemd-backlight@leds:dell::kbd_backlight.service
       652ms snap-gnome\x2dlogs-45.mount
       639ms snap-gnome\x2dcharacters-117.mount
       624ms systemd-timesyncd.service
       598ms systemd-journald.service
       592ms snap-gnome\x2dlogs-40.mount
       584ms snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d26\x2d1604-59.mount
       560ms systemd-random-seed.service
       552ms snap-gnome\x2dcalculator-260.mount
       543ms upower.service
       536ms snap-gnome\x2dcharacters-139.mount
       522ms snap-gnome\x2dlogs-43.mount
       481ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
       455ms dev-mqueue.mount
       436ms dev-hugepages.mount
       436ms kmod-static-nodes.service
       435ms systemd-remount-fs.service
       435ms sys-kernel-debug.mount
       434ms ufw.service
       387ms systemd-user-sessions.service
       372ms plymouth-read-write.service
       371ms plymouth-start.service
       286ms snapd.seeded.service
       219ms snap-gnome\x2dsystem\x2dmonitor-57.mount
       200ms setvtrgb.service
       145ms bolt.service
       131ms systemd-update-utmp.service
       116ms boot-efi.mount
        88ms user@1000.service
        80ms ifupdown-pre.service
        24ms rtkit-daemon.service
        15ms systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service
        14ms snapd.socket
         1ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount
         1ms sys-kernel-config.mount
```